# Setting retry policy for Azure Topics

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

How do i specify retry policy for Azure Topic, I am using following code format

```
 var topicClient = serviceBusFactory.CreateTopicClient("TopicName");
 topicClient.RetryPolicy = ??
 topicClient.Send(message);
```

Also does servicebus have some internal retry mechanism.

Comment: did you really find answer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can find the answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.retrypolicy.aspx). The default is RetryExponential or NoRetry.

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more with the key points of the article in case the link goes bad or changes.